# Setting propper permissions for a dropbox and a reader only gets me half-way

Tags: linux, permissions

I have successfully created an ftp directory where the ftp user has only write permissions.  It's essentially a drop box.  I created another user that has both read and write permissions to the directory.

If the first user is *ups* and the second is *home* this is what the permissions look like:

> drwx-wx--x 3 home ups

Somehow *home* still can see the files within the directory but can't manipulate them, the command "cp" fails.  I can if use the same command as **su**, which I know is a bad idea.  Just did that to test that I had no typos.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your listed permissions are part of `ls -l`, then the directory is owned by `home` in the group `ups`, in which case `home` has read permission and so can browse the directory, as well as the write permission allowing creating, renaming and deleting files.

If the user `ups` is in the group `ups`, then group permissions allows the user to create, rename and delete files, but not to browse and see which files exist in the directory. So this user can delete the files he has uploaded and any other files known to exist, but without the ability to list the directory to find out their names.

In order to use `cp`, `home` needs read access to the files in the directory, which I assume he or she doesn't have. What you need to do is to make sure that uploaded *files* have read permission for `home` (eg with `umask 022`). This point can be confirmed if you update your question to include the file permissions within the directory.

Comment: You're correct, despite the fact that
 for the directory I have:


**drwx-wx--x 3 home ups 4096 Aug 15 18:18 files**

within the directory it states:

**-rw------- 1 ups ups 285928 Aug 14 19:06 data1.txt**


So obviously I don't have a full grasp of how permissions work.  I figured home having all permissions to the directory would include the directory's contents.

Comment: It's logical, but confusing for anyone who has worked with Windows, where basic file permissions determine some of the directory options, such as deletion, that are controlled by the directory permissions in Unix/Linux. Also, there is no deny read option in the basic permissions, though there is if you use ACLs.

Comment: Forgive my densness  @AFH but then how can I make  it so that home has all rights over ups while keeping ups to write only permission? Yes, am stuck in a Windows frame of mind

Comment: I tried umask 022 under home, but in the end any file uploaded by ups is still listed with ups as owner and group.

Comment: The `umask` value affects the permissions, but not ownership: any files created by a user will be owned by that user with the associated group. So `umask 022` will give `-rw-r--r--`, assuming the creator doesn't want executable permission, but this mask needs to be in the file creator's account, `ups`, so that `ups` can read and write the file through owner permissions, and `home`, being in the same `ups` group, can therefore read and copy it through group permissions.

Comment: I'm just failing here.  I even turned ups's mask to 777 and it still didn't work, so am going to restart the question from the start.  Thanks anyway

Comment: The `umask` value works in reverse (bits set in it are _not_ set in the created file permissions), so `0777` creates files with _no_ access permissions (`--------`), which is rarely useful.

Comment: So I did the reverse, 
 **schlomo@sdc-server:~/ftp/files$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx** 
And it still fails,could there be a umask for ftp?

Comment: Hey @AFH Here's where I'm at now...…

Yes, I realized there's a different umask for FTP.....DUH.  Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: I knew something need to be done on the target machine, but I don't have a Linux FTP server configured, so I was limited in what I could check. Glad you've solved it.